# PHP Convert Unicode to text

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am receiving from a form the following urlencoded string    `%F0%9D%90%B4%F0%9D%91%99%F0%9D%91%92%F0%9D%91%97%F0%9D%91%8E%F0%9D%91%9B%F0%9D%91%91%F0%9D%91%9F%F0%9D%91%8E`

If I decode it I get the following formatted text:

Is there any way with PHP to get the plain "Alejandra" text from the encoded or decoded string?
I have tried without success several ways to do it with

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-16",mb_detect_encoding($string))

iconv('utf-16', 'utf-8', rawurldecode($string)
```

and any other solution I could in stackoverflow.

Edit:
I tried the proposed solution $strAscii = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$str); but it deletes the special characters such as áéíóúñç which we need to stay.

Expected result
input: 
output: Alejandra

input: Álejandra
output: Álejandra

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also known as [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). However, without context we also have to guess the encoding. Why has the HTML form not defined the text encoding?

Answer (score 2):

urldecode or rawurldecode is sufficient.

```
$string = "%F0%9D%90%B4%F0%9D%91%99%F0%9D%91%92%F0%9D%91%97%F0%9D%91%8E%F0%9D%91%9B%F0%9D%91%91%F0%9D%91%9F%F0%9D%91%8E";
$str = urldecode($string);
var_dump($str);
//string(36) ""
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/OMQ35

A special debugger gives me: string(36) UTF-8mb4. This means that there are also UTF-8 characters in the string that require 4 bytes. The character A is the [Unicode character “” (U+1D434)](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+1D434).

Note:

If the special UTF-8 characters cause problems, you can try to display the strings as ASCII characters with iconv.

```
$strAscii = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$str);  
//string(9) "Alejandra"
```

Comment: 4 bytes per character can be seen easily when noticing that byte `%F0` repeats in the same interval - a particular [high value for UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=119860&number=512).

Comment: Thank you @jspit, I think the //TRANSLIT in iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$str); was what I was missing to get the name in plain text.

Comment: Thanks for the `ASCII/TRANSLIT` tip there. For anyone else reading, this will create brackets around some characters, e.g. `"ⓣ" => "(t)"`

Comment: If a character cannot be represented in the target character set, an attempt is made to approximate it with one or more similar-looking characters. "€ and £" ->  "EUR and lb". More https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: I edited the question since we tested the proposed solution but found out that this deletes special characters such as áéí´..ñç  and we would need those to stay.
Expected result
input:   output: Alejandra
input Álejandra  output: Alejandra
I tried with different combinations but couldn't make it work for both cases.

Comment: I can't see special characters being deleted. The Unicode character "Á" which is not ASCII becomes an Ascii "A". Just like the "". Your question does not contain a clear objective. You should specify that. Which Unicode characters should be replaced by ASCII and which which you need to stay? If you need very specific single exceptions then you must use the solution by #Jacob Mulquin.

Comment: Thank you for following this issue. What I need is that if I receive a text such as "" it is converted to "Alejandra" but if I receive a text such as "Álejandra" of "Iñigo" it stays "Álejandra" or "Iñigo" with the special characters. Thank you again for your help. We tried everything we can think of.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is called a "psuedo-alphabet", you can see a list of them here: https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi. The one that you appear to be getting can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols

Basically what you need to do is take the string, split it and use a lookup table to convert it back to regular characters. This implementation is terribly efficient but that's because I grabbed the alphabets from the above Wikipedia page and was too lazy to reorganise it.

```
function math_symbols_to_plain_text($input, $alphabet)
{
    $alphabets = [
        ['a','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['b','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['c','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['d','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['e','','','','','','','','ℯ','','','','',''],
        ['f','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['g','','','','','','','','ℊ','','','','',''],
        ['h','','ℎ','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['i','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['j','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['k','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['l','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['m','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['n','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['o','','','','','','','','ℴ','','','','',''],
        ['p','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['q','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['r','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['s','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['t','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['u','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['v','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['w','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['x','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['y','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['z','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['A','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['B','','','','','','','','ℬ','','','','',''],
        ['C','','','','','','','','','','ℭ','','','ℂ'],
        ['D','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['E','','','','','','','','ℰ','','','','',''],
        ['F','','','','','','','','ℱ','','','','',''],
        ['G','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['H','','','','','','','','ℋ','','ℌ','','','ℍ'],
        ['I','','','','','','','','ℐ','','ℑ','','',''],
        ['J','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['K','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['L','','','','','','','','ℒ','','','','',''],
        ['M','','','','','','','','ℳ','','','','',''],
        ['N','','','','','','','','','','','','','ℕ'],
        ['O','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['P','','','','','','','','','','','','','ℙ'],
        ['Q','','','','','','','','','','','','','ℚ'],
        ['R','','','','','','','','ℛ','','ℜ','','','ℝ'],
        ['S','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['T','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['U','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['V','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['W','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['X','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['Y','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        ['Z','','','','','','','','','','ℨ','','','ℤ']
    ];

    $replace = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

    $lookup = [
        'serif-normal',
        'serif-bold',
        'serif-italic',
        'serif-bolditalic',
        'sans-normal',
        'sans-bold',
        'sans-italic',
        'sans-bolditalic',
        'script-normal',
        'script-bold',
        'franktur-normal',
        'fraktur-bold',
        'monospace',
        'doublestruck'
    ];

    $map_index = array_search($alphabet, $lookup);

    $split = mb_str_split($input);

    $output = '';
    foreach ($split as $char) {
        foreach ($alphabets as $i => $letter) {
            if ($letter[$map_index] === $char)
                $output .= $replace[$i];
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

$input = '';
$output = math_symbols_to_plain_text($input, 'serif-italic');

echo $input . PHP_EOL . $output . PHP_EOL;
```

Yields:

```
Alejandra
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to decode URL then why you are not trying to use `urldecode()`
follow this .[PHP DOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: This post can be improved by reading OP's text again and by using much more punctuation.